# IHttpActionResult vs async Task<IHttpActionResult>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

Most Web API 2.0 methods I've seen return `IHttpActionResult`, which is defined as an interface that "defines a command that asynchronously creates a System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage".

I'm a little confused about what's going on when a method is returning `async Task<IHttpActionResult>`.

Why would you use one over the other?  Or are these functionally identical - isn't `IHttpActionResult` already asynchronous?

Comment: You need to return a `Task<IHttpActionResult>` when you are using the `async` and `await` feature.

Comment: @Romoku So the idea is that you'd only use `async` whenever you'd need to implement threading?  In the context of Web API methods that perform simple CRUD operations, is there any functional difference between using a method that returns `IHttpActionResult` vs `async Task<IHttpActionResult>`?

Comment: Using `async` there may be performance improvements at scale, but it is negligible for most web applications. There is no functional difference between sync and async.

Comment: @Romoku Thanks, this was a little bit confusing to me.  If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference between using `IHttpActionResult` and `async Task<IHttpActionResult>` is whether any of your code utilizes the `async` and `await` feature. Many libraries like Entity Framework provide `async` versions of methods (e.g. `SaveChangesAsync`) that provide a slight performance increase. However, there are pitfalls to using `async` with Web API, so unless you understand many of the idiosyncrasies it is prudent to stick to the synchronous API.

Steven Cleary has a lot of information on [his blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/) about the idiosyncrasies of `async` and `await`. To get started I advise looking at [Don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: He's not comparing an asynchronous API to a synchronous API, he's comparing an asynchronous API to a different type of asynchronous API.

Answer (score 23):

Your action may return an `IHttpActionResult` which performs the action asynchronously when the framework calls its `ExecuteAsync`.

But if you must first make some other async calls before creating and returning the result, then you're forced to change the signature to `async Task<IHttpActionResult>`. That's all it is.

If your controller action code doesn't use `await` then you can switch back to the simpler signature. However, the result you return will still be asynchronous.

To be clear, in both cases, you are using asynchronous code.

The performance benefit is that - provided all calls to the deepest level are async - a web server thread is not blocked during disk or network I/O, your server can handle more requests with fewer resources.

Think carefully before calling `Wait` or `Result` on a Task, or creating a Task yourself within ASP.NET code.

Two legitimate reasons to hand-code, intentional multi-threading or parallelism for web server code are:

- when it receives minimal traffic but performs computational work, a call every so often to run a computation over data and you want to use all 16 cores.
- when making >1 simultaneous calls to database shards or >1 other services, you'd make a task for each shard query up front and await them all.