# Effectively use async/await with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am trying to make use of the `async/await` feature of ASP.NET in my Web API project. I am not very sure whether it will make any difference in performance of my Web API service. Please find below the workflow and sample code from my application.

**Work Flow:**

UI Application → Web API endpoint(controller) → Call method in Web API service layer → Call another external web service. (Here we have the DB interactions, etc.)

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCountries()
{
    var allCountrys = await CountryDataService.ReturnAllCountries();

    if (allCountrys.Success)
    {
        return Ok(allCountrys.Domain);
    }

    return InternalServerError();
}
```

**Service Layer:**

```
public Task<BackOfficeResponse<List<Country>>> ReturnAllCountries()
{
    var response = _service.Process<List<Country>>(BackOfficeEndpoint.CountryEndpoint, "returnCountries");

    return Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

I tested the above code and is working. But I am not sure whether it is the correct usage of `async/await`. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Related posts - [best practice for using async await in webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42276149/465053)

Answer (score 242, accepted):

> I am not very sure whether it will make any difference in performance of my API.

Bear in mind that the primary benefit of asynchronous code on the server side is *scalability*. It won't magically make your requests run faster. I cover several "should I use `async`" considerations in my [article on `async` ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

I think your use case (calling other APIs) is well-suited for asynchronous code, just bear in mind that "asynchronous" does not mean "faster". The best approach is to first make your **UI** responsive and asynchronous; this will make your app *feel* faster even if it's slightly slower.

As far as the code goes, this is not asynchronous:

```
public Task<BackOfficeResponse<List<Country>>> ReturnAllCountries()
{
  var response = _service.Process<List<Country>>(BackOfficeEndpoint.CountryEndpoint, "returnCountries");
  return Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

You'd need a truly asynchronous implementation to get the scalability benefits of `async`:

```
public async Task<BackOfficeResponse<List<Country>>> ReturnAllCountriesAsync()
{
  return await _service.ProcessAsync<List<Country>>(BackOfficeEndpoint.CountryEndpoint, "returnCountries");
}
```

Or (if your logic in this method really is just a pass-through):

```
public Task<BackOfficeResponse<List<Country>>> ReturnAllCountriesAsync()
{
  return _service.ProcessAsync<List<Country>>(BackOfficeEndpoint.CountryEndpoint, "returnCountries");
}
```

Note that it's easier to work from the "inside out" rather than the "outside in" like this. In other words, don't start with an asynchronous controller action and then force downstream methods to be asynchronous. Instead, identify the naturally asynchronous operations (calling external APIs, database queries, etc), and make those asynchronous at the *lowest* level first (`Service.ProcessAsync`). Then let the `async` trickle up, making your controller actions asynchronous as the last step.

And under no circumstances should you use `Task.Run` in this scenario.

Comment: Could you explain why you shoudl not use Task.Run here?

Comment: @Maarten: I explain it (briefly) in [the article I linked to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx). I go into more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Comment: I've read your article Stephen and it seems to avoid mentioning something. When a ASP.NET request arrives and begins it is running on a thread pool thread, that's fine. But if it becomes async then yes it initiates the async processing and that thread returns to the pool right away. But the work performed in the async method will itself execute on a thread pool thread!

Comment: @Hugh: [Asynchronous I/O operations do not block a thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Answer (score 14):

It is correct, but perhaps not useful.

As there is nothing to wait on – no calls to blocking APIs which could operate asynchronously – then you are setting up structures to track asynchronous operation (which has overhead) but then not making use of that capability.

For example, if the service layer was performing DB operations with Entity Framework which supports asynchronous calls:

```
public Task<BackOfficeResponse<List<Country>>> ReturnAllCountries()
{
    using (db = myDBContext.Get()) {
      var list = await db.Countries.Where(condition).ToListAsync();

       return list;
    }
}
```

You would allow the worker thread to do something else while the db was queried (and thus able to process another request).

Await tends to be something that needs to go all the way down: it is very hard to retro-fit into an existing system.

Answer (score 0):

You are not leveraging async / await effectively because the request thread will be blocked while executing the *synchronous* method `ReturnAllCountries()`

The thread that is assigned to handle a request will be idly waiting while `ReturnAllCountries()` does it's work.

If you can implement `ReturnAllCountries()` to be asynchronous, then you would see scalability benefits. This is because the thread could be released back to the .NET thread pool to handle another request, while `ReturnAllCountries()` is executing. This would allow your service to have higher throughput, by utilizing threads more efficiently.

Comment: This is not true. The socket is connected but the thread processing the request can do something else, such as process a different request, while waiting on a service call.

Answer (score -9):

I would change your service layer to:

```
public Task<BackOfficeResponse<List<Country>>> ReturnAllCountries()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return _service.Process<List<Country>>(BackOfficeEndpoint.CountryEndpoint, "returnCountries");
    }      
}
```

as you have it, you are still running your `_service.Process` call synchronously, and gaining very little or no benefit from awaiting it.

With this approach, you are wrapping the potentially slow call in a `Task`, starting it, and returning it to be awaited.  Now you get the benefit of awaiting the `Task`.

Comment: As per the blog [link](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-you-shouldnt-create-asynchronous-wrappers-with-task-run/), I could see that even if we use Task.Run the method still runs synchronously?

Comment: Hmm.  There are a lot of differences between the above code and that link.  Your `Service` is not an async method, and is not being awaited within the `Service` call itself.  I can understand his point, but I don't believe it applies here.

Comment: `Task.Run` should be avoided on ASP.NET. This approach would remove all benefits from `async`/`await` and actually perform worse under load than just a synchronous call.